I'm only able to view the axis of selected object in the viewport when move tool is activated manually
Currently when I select the object in outliner I have to manually hit the move tool in the toolbar to display the axis of the selected objects:

Is there a hotkey shortcut to active the move tool as if I had hit the move tool button?
If I am in select lasso mode and hit "G" the ability to move the object is activated but I do not see the axis in the viewport until I hit the move toolbar button:

If I go to Viewport> Overlays > Object Gizmos Options and check "Move" then the 3 axis of the object are visible whenever the object is selected but also when the move tool is not activated.
The desired result would be a hot key to active the 3 axis on selected object only when the move tool is active as if I had pressed the toolbar move button.
Is there a way to do that?
Thank you.
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
I

The gizmos are disabled during transform operations performed with operators so that they don't obstruct the view in such operations. If you want to see the gizmos, they are visible(or partially visible) when you use the tools(as opposed to operators like  G ,  R ,  S ). You can hit  Shift  +  Spacebar  to get a menu for choosing tools:

As you see they have shortcuts in the menu, so you could hit  Shift  +  Spacebar  followed by  G  to activate the move tool quickly. You can also add it to your quick favorites( Q ) menu or assign another hotkey by right clicking on the tools:

